# Domo - Split multi value comma-delimited column based on values

Tags: multivalue, domo

I have a data source in Domo with a multi value column that is comma delimited. I am able to split the column using the comma as delimiter, into new columns.
Example-

- fruit, vegetables        Gives new column 1 Fruit and new column 2 vegetables
- Vegetables, meat         Gives new column 1 vegetables and new column 2 meat

I need it to group all fruit into one column and all vegetables into another.

How can I do this?